# 5- star survey for mobile GIS app iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, gis, geospatial, postgis

I am currently trying develop a mobile app using the ArcGIS Runtime SDK on iOS.  Right now users receive a push-notification requesting feedback when they visit a location predetermined using a feature layer.  What I would like to add to the push-notification is a way for users to answer a three question 5-star survey.  Results would need to be averaged and then populated back to the feature layer to be displayed via callout box to users.(i.e. name, address, and 5-star results would display).

I'm not sure where to start so I am open to any advice, tutorials, or workflows on implementing this (or good Samaritans willing to hold my hand). I have tried to piece together pieces of information found in different forums but I haven't found how to link it all together. Maybe using PostGIS in some manner?   My skill level is novice, yet dangerous!

I know these forums are sometimes known for disregarding beginners, so thanks  for taking the time to read my post.

Comment: Since this is specifically about the ArcGIS SDK for iOS, you may also want to ask this question on the [GIS StackExchange](http://gis.stackexchange.com/). The folks there are more likely to understand what you mean by "feature layer" and PostGIS. I don't think it's wrong to post it here but I thought it'd be useful for you to know there's a whole StackExchange site for GIS.

Comment: You should also distill your question to the specific thing you're having trouble with. It sounds like you've already got the push-notification part working. Is the issue how to save the response? Is the issue updating the feature layer?

Comment: Thanks BSMP I will definitely post my question there and yes, the push-notifications are working fine.  

The question/issue is two-fold:
1) how to collect, store, and compile the responses.  
2) How to update the feature layer.